# Google VM instance domain issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, nslookup, dig

I am trying to get my domain (moviefinder.app) to connect to http://34.67.108.103/.  I have followed the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial).

The second last step seems to be working `$ dig +trace moviefinder.app`

[image]

But the last step `$ nslookup moviefinder.app` gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: Pasting the error text into the question would help more than image links. Are you running nslookup on GCE or your desktop? It's returning an unroutable address, is that coming from a HOSTS file or something?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until [DNS propagation](https://www.siteground.com/kb/what_is_dns_propagation_and_why_it_takes_so_long/) is completed.

DNS records are not a instant process, It means you need to wait for a DNS record updates because it is time required for DNS servers worldwide to update their cached information for a domain name.

You can check whether your DNS propagation is completed or not in [here](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)

EDIT) I missed your dns setup is worked fine with dig command, I think cause of this result is difference of dig and nslookup, Please refer to this [link](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch12_01.htm)

Comment: Thank you! The domain name isn't functional yet; I think I will just have to be patient.